# Java GUI Console

Tags: java, console

I have made a full 2d game using Java. (This game is for my project so I am unable to put the code here). - Using JFrames!!

I will like to add something like the eclipse 'console' to the GUI keeping record of all the moves.

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: What are you using for your display? A JFrame? LWJGL? Something else?

Comment: Without any code, we can't really know what you have or what you want. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Using a jframe sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new JFrame, append all moves to it. Display same to user. You can also give option to undo last move. By the move store by you.

Best of luck!!! :)